# My program will loop regardless of whatever char I enter

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I have been working on a very very basic calculation program in C++. It calculates the square root of a number, and also squares it if the user wants. This is what I have so far (I know it's probably rubbish code, but I'm a beginner just experimenting to see how it all works. Any suggestions greatly appreciated though):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int number;         // Global variables to be used in void functions as well as main.
int squaredNumber;
double sqrtResult;
char input;
char useAgain;

void squareNum();       // Prototypes for the void functions
void sqrtNum();
void useAgainQuery();

int main()
{
retry:                      // Establishing somewhere to send user if their input is invalid.
    system("cls");
    cout << "Square Calcualtions" << endl;
    cout << "******************" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Do you want to square a number or find the square root of a number?" << endl;
    cout << "Please select 1 or 2 respectively." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cin >> input;
    if (input == '1')
    {
        cout << "Please press ENTER to continue." << endl;
        cin.ignore().get();
        squareNum();                // If the input is 1, run the void to square a number.
    }
    else if (input == '2')
    {
        cout << "Please press ENTER to continue." << endl;
        cin.ignore().get();
        sqrtNum();                  // If the input is 2, run the void to sqrt a number.
    }
    else if (input != '1' || '2')
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Square Calcualtions" << endl;
        cout << "******************" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Your selection was invalid, please enter 1 or 2." << endl;
        cin.ignore().get();
        goto retry;             // If the input isn't either 1 or 2, send back to the start of program.
    }
    return 0;
}

void squareNum()  // function to square the inputted number.
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "Square Calcualtions" << endl;
    cout << "******************" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the number you want to square." << endl;
    cin >> number;
    cout << "You have chosen: " << number << endl;
    cout << "Press ENTER to calculate." << endl;
    cin.ignore().get();
    system("cls");
    squaredNumber = number * number;        // Simple maths to find the square number
    cout << "You have squared " << number << "." << endl;
    cout << "The result was " << squaredNumber << "." << endl;
    cout << "Press ENTER to continue." << endl;
    cin.get();
    useAgainQuery();
    return;
}

void sqrtNum()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "Square Calcualtions" << endl;
    cout << "******************" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the number you would like the square root of." << endl;
    cin >> number;
    cout << "You have chosen: " << number << "." << endl;
    cout << "Press ENTER to calculate." << endl;
    cin.ignore().get();
    system("cls");
    sqrtResult = sqrt(number);
    cout << "You have found the square root of " << number << "." << endl;
    cout << "The result was: " << sqrtResult << "." << endl;
    cout << "Press ENTER to continue." << endl;
    cin.get();
    useAgainQuery();
    return;
}

void useAgainQuery()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "Square Calcualtions" << endl;
    cout << "******************" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Would you like to make another calculation?" << endl;
    cout << "Y for Yes and N for No." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cin >> useAgain;
    if (useAgain == 'Y' || 'y')
    {
    retry2:                     // Establishing somewhere to send user if their input is invalid.
        system("cls");
        cout << "Square Calcualtions" << endl;
        cout << "******************" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Do you want to square a number or find the square root of a number?" << endl;
        cout << "Please select 1 or 2 respectively." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cin >> input;
        if (input == '1')
        {
            cout << "Please press ENTER to continue." << endl;
            cin.ignore().get();
            squareNum();                // If the input is 1, run the void to square a number.
        }
        else if (input == '2')
        {
            cout << "Please press ENTER to continue." << endl;
            cin.ignore().get();
            sqrtNum();                  // If the input is 2, run the void to sqrt a number.
        }
        else if (input != '1' || '2')
        {
            system("cls");
            cout << "Square Calcualtions" << endl;
            cout << "******************" << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Your selection was invalid, please enter 1 or 2." << endl;
            cin.ignore().get();
            goto retry2;
        }
    }
    else if (useAgain != 'Y' || 'y')
        return;
    return;
}
```

So yeah, when I go through and it asks "Would you like to play again", it goes through it over and over. It doesn't matter what key I press but it loops. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I recommend replacing the `goto retry` with a `do-while` or a `while` loop.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews How would I go about doing this? I have heard goto is a bad one to use, but how do I use a while loop?

Comment: Have you covered `for`, `while` and `do-while` loops in your studies?  I like: `bool user_error = true; while (user_error) { /*...*/};`. Set the variable to false if there is no user error (inside the loop).  Some people use `while(true)` and then the `break` statement if there is no user error.

Answer (score 3):

Change your condition here:

```
    if (useAgain == 'Y' || 'y')
```

to

```
    if (useAgain == 'Y' || useAgain=='y')
```

Also, change this:

```
 else if (useAgain != 'Y' || 'y')
{
    return;
}
```

to this:

```
else if (useAgain != 'Y' && useAgain!='y')
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. Just out of curiosity, why do you use the && instead of just repeating the same process as the one above?

Comment: @IainAnderson: so that both the conditions are met, i.e., it should be true only when `useAgain` is neither `y` nor `Y`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use goto, use a while(1) instead.
2. your last if statement is wrong, it needs to be

   `if (input != '1' && input != '2')`

Comment: Thanks, adding the && fixed it. How does the while(1) work? How would I implement it to be a better alternative to goto?

Comment: It will loop till you will use "break" statement on certain condition, say the person enters 'q' to quit the application.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try creating a bool variable that controls the entire main loop, like this:

```
#include <InsertLibrariesHere>
int main(){
    bool running=true;
    while(running){
        //calculations here
        //continue(Y/N)?
        if (input == N || input == n){running = false;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your comparisons to letters:

```
if (std::toupper(useAgain) == 'Y')
```

or

```
if (std::tolower(useAgain) == 'y')
```

You can also convert the case after you input:

```
cin >> useAgain;
useAgain = std::toupper(useAgain);
if (useAgain == 'Y')
```

There is also `std::transform` is you need to transform a `std::string` to all lower or all upper case.